# What are the main syntax changes in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, legacy-code, backwards-compatibility

Also, I'm wondering what effect upgrading to Ruby 1.9 would have on legacy code from version 1.86. Is the new version backwards compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sam Ruby has a good slideshow of the major changes: [Ruby 1.9: What to Expect](http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/ruby19.html)

Just to highlight a few things that could break your code:

- Single character strings
- {"a", "b"} no longer makes a hash
- Block variables now shadow local variables

Answer (score 4):

I guess that depends on what version you're looking to maintain compatibility with.  The [CHANGELOG](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS) describes the major revisions since the last update including syntax changes, enhancements and bugfixes

Answer (score 4):

Some things are backwards compatible, but many aren't.

For a near complete overview of all the changes (including examples) in 1.9.x, check out <del>[Eigenclass's blog](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?Changes+in+Ruby+1.9)</del> [last archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20090423003136/http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?Changes+in+Ruby+1.9) of Eigenclass's blog.